# Domain and subdomains with nginx from the same server

Tags: nginx

More dev than ops here. Situation: I have a home server (fedora) running a few applications using podman. Some are database services and use various ports. Can this work in NGINX?

- host personal site through `domain.dev`. It lives on `localhost:8080`.
- host the Fedora cockpit through `cocking.domain.dev`. It lives on `localhost:9090`.
- host the other applications through sub domains of their own, with their various ports `db.domain.dev:30001` which live on `localhost:30001`. I think I have 15 ports used all in all.

Cockpit I think I can do (it uses websockets)

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
upstream websocket {
  server localhost:9090;
}
server {
  server_name cockpit.domain.dev;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://websocket;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Origin https://$host;
  }
}
```

Can I simply add another `location /` for domain `domain.dev`?

I can open my modem to pass on all the required ports. If possible, I have a follow-up question later about certbot, google domains and google dns. I *cannot* get that to work.

Comment: You should get certbot working _first_ as the browser will only access .dev domains using https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, bear in mind nginx is an HTTP proxy, so you can only proxy requests over HTTP(S) protocol.

Second, I think I'll need to map a different port to your localhost port, once the O.S. won't allow two different applications and process bind the same port.

The config below is supposed to work for you (note that I'm mapping port 18080 to localhost:8080 and port 19090 to localhost:9090):

```
server {
    listen 18080;

    server_name domain.dev;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.dev-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.dev-error.log error;
    
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen 19090;

    server_name cockpit.domain.dev;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/cockpit.domain.dev-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/cockpit.domain.dev-error.log error;
    
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. Do you think this will still work with the websocket that cockpit needs?

Comment: both servers could listen to port 443, otherwise just having multiple server blocks worked

Comment: @Jorg, you mentioned "localhost" in your examples, which made me think you're proxying requests to the same machine (localhost)